# Spring Batch Automatically Commits Updates On Database Even Without Specifying It on ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-batch

I'm testing Spring Batch for my next project. In my step I indicated my `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, and `ItemWriter`.

On my `ItemReader` I'm fetching the ID's only using `JdbcPagingItemReader` and passing it to `ItemProcessor` where it fetch the whole entity using `JpaRepository.findOne()`. I'm applying the Driving Query Pattern here.

On the same time in my `ItemProcessor` implementation, I'm setting one of its field: `setUpdated(new Date())`.

Then on my `ItemWriter`, I'm just logging the passed entity from the `ItemProcessor`.

My question is when I check the logs, hibernate is updating the entities value in the table even though in my `ItemWriter` I'm just logging it.

ItemProcessor implementation:

```
public class IdToContractItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<BigDecimal, Contract> {
    
    @Override
    public Contract process(BigDecimal id) {
         Contract contract = repo.findOne(id.longValue());
         contract.setUpdated(new Date());
         return contract;
    }  
}
```

ItemWriter implementation:

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Contract> {
     
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Contract> list) {
        for (Contract c : list) {
            log.info("id {}", c.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Step bean:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
             .get("myStep")
             .<BigDecimal, Contract>chunk(3)
             .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader)
             .processor(idToContractItemProcessor)
             .writer(customWriter)
             .build();
}
```

Contract item is an entity class.

Why is that every after 3 Contracts (chunk), hibernate logs update statement even though I'm not saving it on `ItemWriter`?

Comment: Because that is how JPA works. When in a transaction, modifications to an entity are automatically persisted, you don't need to call `persist` or `merge` on the entity manager. Regarding your setup, you are aware that your method is slow (ids then entities) and is basically a 1+N select issue you have in your batch).

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum thank you for that clarification about the transaction. I get it now :). 
Also I'm using the ids-then-entities because at first I was using the JpaPagingItemReader and updating the entity's status (which is also part of my where clause in ItemReader ) skips some item during pagination. And that's the solution they recommended to me. If you have any recommendation to avoid the 1+N select, that would be great. I'm still exploring this Spring Batch. Anyway thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you use pagination you must make sure you are using an order by as well else it won't work and you will miss items.

Comment: I've tried adding order by id, but upon checking the logs and my table, it is still skipping items after updating the entity.

Comment: ah yes. The problem is that the update also influences the result of the query. So you start with a selection of 100, after updating (depending on your chunk size) this is reduced to (97). What you can do is instead of using paging, write an item reader that issues a query and always returns the top x (where x is the chunk size) that way you won't loose records.